# Assign each value to separate list element without loop

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply

Let's consider the numbers following:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(100, replace = T)
evens <- x[x%%2 == 0]
```

I want to have each element of evens as seperate element of the list. So doing this with for is really simple:

```
lst <- list()

for (i in seq_len(length(evens))) lst[[i]] <- evens[i]
```

However I'm not so sure how to do it without loop. I think some magic can be made using `lapply` however I don't know how to use it. Could you please give me a hand ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, do you mean a list like below?

```
as.list(evens)
```

---

If you want to use `lapply`, you can try

```
lapply(evens, c)
```

Comment: @PKumar Haha, yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
tapply(x, x %% 2 == 0, function(x) x)
```

Comment: `function (x) x` is already defined in R: it’s called `identity`.